# Hibernate mapping a second @Embeddable field in a subclass

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, annotations

I'm trying to map an @Embeddable object in a subclass whose parent class already has a field of that @Embeddable type.

The hibernate [Embeddable Objects documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#d0e483) claims I can use the @AttributeOverrides to override the column names of an @Embeddable object:

e.g.

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    // Persistent component using defaults
    Address homeAddress;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
            @AttributeOverride(name="iso2", column = @Column(name="bornIso2") ),
            @AttributeOverride(name="name", column = @Column(name="bornCountryName") )
    } )
    Country bornIn;
    ...
}
```

Here's the case I have:

```
 @Embeddable
    public class ContentID implements Serializable {
        @Column(name="contentID")
        private String contentPath;
    }

   @MappedSuperclass
   public abstract class BaseDomainObject implements Serializable  {

       @Embedded
       private ContentID contentID;
    }

public class Achievement extends BaseDomainObject {

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="contentID", column = @Column(name="awardedItem") ),
    } )
    private ContentID awardedItem;
}
```

The error I get is:

> org.hibernate.MappingException:
>   Repeated column in mapping for entity:
>   Achievement column: contentID (should
>   be mapped with insert="false"
>   update="false")   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:652)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:674)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:670)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:696)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:450)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass.validate(SingleTableSubclass.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1108)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1293)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)

**UPDATE:**

I looked in for Hibernate issues relating to this and the GRAILS project claimed they fixed this issue but their annotation solution doesn't seem to be valid javax.persistence annotations (maybe it's a new version).

[JPA @Embeddable/@Embedded throws org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3225)

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you embed country instead of using a relationship?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be this:

```
 public class ContentID implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="contentID")
    private String contentPath;
}
```

You are making the contentPath column name to be "contentId" and that is clashing with your AttributeOverride annotation later on.

Try this:

```
public class ContentID implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="contentPath")
    private String contentPath;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I am also wondering about this:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides( {
    @AttributeOverride(name="contentID", column = @Column(name="awardedItem") ),
} )
private ContentID awardedItem;
```

You seem to be changing the name of the contentId column here to awardedItem. Is that really necessary?

Comment: The issue is not caused by the @AttributeOverride in Achievement, but because of the @Embedded ContentID that is in Achievement's base class BaseDomainObject.

The trouble is in hibernate mappings the inheritance causes the object to have 2 Embedded ContentID objects as contentID column which I thought AttributeOverride would take care of it.

Even if I removed the @Column(name="contentID") I think the issue would remain.

Answer (score 2):

Vincent is right. The `attributeOverride` Name field is referring to a column name when it should be a attribute/property of a class.

```
@AttributeOverrides( {
    @AttributeOverride(name="contentPath", column = @Column(name="awardedItem") ),
} )
```

Notice that the name is for the class property not the database column.

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

```
@JoinColumn(insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

as a workaround.